# Microsoft Graph API query parameters via powershell not recognized

Tags: powershell, api, graph, azure-active-directory

I've registered an app using the Azure AD portal which I am successfully accessing using invoke-webrequest from a Powershell script.  The app tries to list signins but is returning up to the limit of 1000 signin objects.  When I try to use query parameters to restrict the fields and amount of data returned, the web request returns an error saying that the AllowedQueryOptions and EnableQueryAttributes need to be updated for the parameters used, eg. select, top, skip.  I've tried v1.0 and beta APIs without success.

Is there a way to manipulate these options via powershell so that the query parameters are recognized?  I've seen some references to OAuth and ASP.NET Core to do this.  Is powershell the "right" way to automate signin retrieval?  Will this functionality to manipulate query options ever come to powershell?

Cheers,
-Emanuel

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph api ?

Comment: Yes, that was my starting point.

Comment: Since you call it in powershell, do you mind use powershell command to request for the signins results instead of call the graph api in powershell ?

Comment: No, I don't need to use the graph api.

Comment: Just FYI: You will likely get more useful answers if you put a code snippet of the failing part of you are attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, if it is unnecessary for you to use graph api, I think use Powershell command is an option for your reference.

You can use this [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadauditsigninlogs?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) in your Powershell:

```
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs
```

If you want to use query parameters to restrict the fields and amount of data returned, you can refer to the sample as below:

```
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Top 5 | Select-Object -Property Id, UserDisplayName
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: FTR, I didn't get the chance to test this as my circumstances changed since my initial post!  The main difference I think between the two approaches, in terms of implementation, is that with the graph api I had an access token generated in Azure AD for a registered app, whereas with the AzureAD module I need to generate and use a credential object to gain access.